# Where to find tnsname.ora - Debian

Tags: oracle, debian, tnsnames

In a Debian machine, I can use tnsping to identify a tnsname.

But I can not found any tnsnames.ora in this machine. (nothing in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/ )

So, how can I find the tns name config file used by tnsping command ?
Is there any command (similar with tnsping) to locate the tnsnames file?

UPDATE: tnsping command result:

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should include your stack trace/error you got

Answer (score 1):

There is no common location and different applications/drivers apply various search paths with different order and precedences.

Check following locations:

- `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/`
- Current directory of application
- `$TNS_ADMIN` (where TNS_ADMIN is environment variable settings)

Just for completeness in case of Windows check also

- Registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN` (for 64 bit)
- Registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN` (for 32 bit)
- .NET config file (i.e. `machine.config` and/or `web.config`)

In ideal case all of them should point to the same location, consider to create symbolic links if needed.

NB, maybe file `tnsnames.ora` simply does not exist. Create such file in location mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in this machine $TNS_ADMIN is not config. I have to config $ORACLE_HOME and $PATH ; $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to run tnsping.

Comment: Refer to this question, you should try to create that file:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28326/how-do-i-generate-a-tnsnames-ora-file-to-connect-to-an-oracle-database

Answer (score 0):

You tell us the tnsping is working... At my place the tnsping tool gives the exact location of the sqlnet.ora it is using.... The tnsnames.ora should be in the same directory.

When your environment is correctly configured the tnsnames should be in the mentioned directory. When it does not exist you could try running the netca command and configure "Naming Methods configuration" and add a destination with "Locale Net Service Name configuration". This utility will create sqlnet.ora en tnsnames.ora in the default location.

```
[oracle@somedir]$ tnsping test                                                                                                                                    

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on 27-JUL-2016 22:00:24                                                                                       

Copyright (c) 1997, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.                                                                                                                   

Used parameter files:                                                                                                                                                     
/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.3/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora                                                                                                  


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias                                                                                                                                
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = TEST)))             
OK (0 msec)
```

Comment: My tnsping command dose not show Used parameter files values. Im update my question to add result image.